# C# Wpf UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Tengo una duda cree mi *UserControl* llamado *cme*, tiene varios controles, lo llamo en el evento `Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) cme.pppBoxPri.Opened += PppBoxPri_Opened;` el carga excelente.

El problema que tengo es que:

1. Cuando hago *click* en el *UserControl*
2. luego hago *click* fuera del *UserControl*
3. presiono de nuevo *click* en el *UserControl*(Me va almacenando en algun lugar el número de veces que clicko en mi *UserControl*)
4. luego presiono en algun control interno del UserControl(ejemplo boton que tiene un metodo de abrir otra ventana)
5. Me abre la mentana y me ejecuta el contenido de mi boton el mismo  numero de veces que quedo almacenado cuando clicque mi *UserControl*

Quiero darle un **dispose** pero no consigo hacerlo en *WPF* que me recomiendan.

Éste parte de mi código:

```html
namespace TelaPadron
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica interna para Consulta.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class COnsulta: Window
    {
        IcmeBotoes EcmeBtnAcaoConsulta = new cmeBotoesUIConsultaEstablecto();


        ComportamentoBotoesParaCme OComportamenteBotoeCme = newComportamentoBotoesParaCme();

        public Consulta() => InitializeComponent();

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CboReferencia.PreencherPesquisaEmitente(cboPesquisaConsultaEmitente);
            cme.pppBoxPri.Opened += PppBoxPri_Opened;
            cme.pppBoxPri.Closed += PppBoxPri_Closed;

        }


        private void PppBoxPri_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cme.pppBoxPri = null;
        }

        private void PppBoxPri_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        OComportamenteBotoeCme.DefinirContenudoBotoesMutavle(cme);
            OComportamenteBotoeCme.DefinirLigacaoParaICmeBotoes(EcmeBtnAcaoConsulta, cme);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Porque queres darle dispose? tiene algo que tenga un metodo dispose?

Comment: no tengo! en windows form yo tenia un control (textbox) y limpiaba con un dispose. tal vez le stoy dando el uso equivocado.

Comment: Dispose es para eliminar recursos que fueron tomados y necesitan un dispose.. los controles por lo general no necesitan dispose...

Comment: gracias por la informacion.

Comment: @gbianchi ve mi respuesta, lo veo un poco te dioso lo que hago porque tendria que repetir ese metodo para cada vez que utilice mi control. que me recomendaria.? tengo problema con esa asignacion de eventos en mi control.

Answer (score 0):

tal vez no es la mejor forma pero resolvi de esta manera, adicionando en el evento closed de mi control y retirando lo que habia adicionado a mi evento opened atraves de mi metodo *PppBoxPri_Closed* (cambie mi +=  por un -= cuando cierro mi control.)

public ConsultaEmitente() => InitializeComponent();

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
        cmePesquisaEstablecto.pppBoxPri.Opened += PppBoxPri_Opened;
        cmePesquisaEstablecto.pppBoxPri.Closed += PppBoxPri_Closed;
        CboReferencia.PreencherPesquisaEmitente(cboPesquisaConsultaEmitente);

    }


    private void PppBoxPri_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cmePesquisaEstablecto.pppBoxPri.Opened -= PppBoxPri_Opened;
    }

    private void PppBoxPri_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OComportamenteBotoeCme.DefinirContenudoBotoesMutavle(cmePesquisaEstablecto);
        OComportamenteBotoeCme.DefinirLigacaoParaICmeBotoes(EcmeBtnAcaoConsulta, cmePesquisaEstablecto);
    }
```